# How to change default action on debug visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vite

here is the problem: I want to debug and run vue 3 vite on lan, so to do the second I just have to run `vite --host` but when I press F5 by default it runs `vite`. How can I change the default command that visual studio code is running so instead of vite it runs vite --host?

My launch.json file:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

I made another question where I explain how I fixed some of the problems In here, still cant get it to debug from external device
[How to debug Vue 3 Vite while on lan --host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159388/how-to-debug-vue-3-vite-while-on-lan-host)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments with either `args` or `runtimeArgs` attributes. Here is [more information](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging) on this. I think in your case this should work:

```
   {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "pwa-chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
          "url": "http://localhost:4000",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
          "args": ["host"],
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would like to know where is the command that is being run when I press F5, and how, becose for example in nodejs project it runs a very long command to run nodemon automatically when pressing F5, or when you debug with jest it writes the entire command to run that test, and idk where the magic is happening. In the case of Vite, it seems that the plugin I have is running It from the plugin configuration, so that may be it.. that may be the answer, idk.

Comment: VS Code is using the default [JavaScript Debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug) extension that debugs Node.js. It will guess the launch settings and will try to run your currently active file. That's where the magic happens. And when you need to change something, that's when you use `launch.json`. Alternatively, you can launch your app from the terminal directly and have the debugger auto attach to your process.