# How to debug Vue 3 Vite while on lan --host

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vite

How can I debug while using --host option on Vue 3 Vite so I can debug my phone instance for example. At the moment Im using visual studio code plugin "Vite"

launch.json:

```
 {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "pwa-chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
          "url": "http://localhost:4000",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
        }
      ]
    }
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host --port 4000",
}
```

Vite config options

[image]

with this I'm being able to run on lan and debug but only on my pc, if I try from my phone or other pc, it connects but it wont stop on any breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to debug any web app, web browser running on your phone must support a debugging protocol. Chrome for Android for example does support what you need, see [Remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) article.

As for another PC, you need to launch Chrome there with a [remote debugging command line switch](https://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html) as well, and then edit your `launch.json` to attach your vs code instance to different host (ip and port). That is of course if you want to be able to set breakpoints in vs code on your developer machine and then reflect that on another PC.

Roughly saying, you need to point your vs code to a running target
browser, for example, in your current config vs code launches instance of Chrome with a debugging switch enabled for you, behind the scenes